# How do i extract some data in string? using PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string of URL format.

It is this.
"http://test.com/foo/bar/detail.php?key=KEY&other=x"

What I need is to extract "KEY" from URL.

It is similar this.

```
$foo = $_GET['key'];
```

But what I have is a string of URL format.
How do i extract KEY this string?

Comment: [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) + [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

Comment: Can you explain your issue a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse_url()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php And `parse-str` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
$string = "http://test.com/foo/bar/detail.php?key=KEY&other=x";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$variable = parse_str($query, $output);
echo $output['key'];
```

Comment: `parse_str` doesn't work like that - you need to pass in an empty array to populate as the second argument

Comment: I like this method. It's very simple. It's able to use in our server because my php version is 5.6